# LAST_INSERT_ID() off by one

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a web application written in Python using SQLAlchemy for data access.  I'm trying to get the last insert ID of an insert.  This code was working when I was using PyODBC, but now with SQLAlchemy it doesn't seem to work.  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` seems to consistently return an ID that is off by one.

```
    query = text("""INSERT INTO HR_PunchBatch
    (StoreID, UserID, Source,Timestamp,Status)
        VALUES (:StoreID,:UserID,:Source,NOW(),:Status)""")

    g.engine.execute(query,
        StoreID=StoreID,
        UserID=session['UserID'],
        Source=source,
        Status='New')

    batch_id = g.engine.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id').fetchone()
    return batch_id['id']
```

Any ideas as to why this would be off by one (returning 8 instead of 9 for example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still not certain why the query was returning an inaccurate ID.  However, I seem to have worked around the problem by getting a connection object rather than using implicit/connectionless execution.  Perhaps it was grabbing two different connections before and therefore providing inconsistent results:

```
    conn = g.engine.connect()

    query = text("""INSERT INTO HR_PunchBatch
        (StoreID, UserID, Source,Timestamp,Status)
        VALUES (:StoreID,:UserID,:Source,NOW(),:Status)""")

    conn.execute(query,
        StoreID=StoreID,
        UserID=session['UserID'],
        Source=source,
        Status='New')

    batch_id = conn.execute('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id').fetchone()

    return batch_id['id']
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look what SQLAlchemy documentation has to say about [Engine.execute](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.execute).

Every time you call this function you are implicitly getting new connection. My guess is that your INSERT is not commited yet when you are selecting last_id in a different session.

Answer (score 1):

**Cursor.lastrowid**

> This read-only attribute provides the rowid of the last modified row
>   (most databases return a rowid only when a single INSERT operation is
>   performed). If the operation does not set a rowid or if the database
>   does not support rowids, this attribute should be set to None.

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'usr', 'pswrd', 'db');
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO  table (name) VALUES "text"')
conn.commit()

print cur.lastrowid # print LAST_INSERT_ID()
```